# How to find string that are in the end of the line in shell script using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a file where I am searching for numbers that are at the end of the line

> Try and Trust, by Horatio Alger, Jr.          1
>
> The Rover Boys at School, by Arthur M. Winfield 11
>
> A Tramp Abroad, Part 1, by Mark Twain        23

if I search for 1, I want to print the first line where 1 is at the end of the line. Not the second line where there is 11, or the third line where 1 is in the middle of the sentence.

```
echo "Enter the content you are searching for:"  
    read foo

if x=$(grep -A 1 -i "$foo\$" GUTINDEX.ALL)
    then echo -e "$x"
fi
```

\$ is for detecting the end of the line but this is not working. Why?

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
$ foo=1
$ awk -v s="$foo" '$NF==s' file
Try and Trust, by Horatio Alger, Jr. 1
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v s="$foo" '  # the search term in s var
$NF==s               # if the last field is equal to s print the record
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a script that allows you to enter a regex (regular expression) as an argument (positional parameter), you can simply use the form

```
grep "$2" "$1"
```

where `"$2"` is the regular expression and `"$1"` the filename. You can also add any additional options for `grep` as desired (like `-A 1` for one line of context after the match, etc..)

A short example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input.\n"
    printf "usage: %s filename regex\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

[ -r "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 2
}

grep "$2" "$1"
```

(**note:** there is no need to escape the `'$'` as it looses its special meaning when contained within a string -- expansion isn't performed -- so long as it is quoted)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash parse.sh gutindex.all '[^0-9]1$'
Try and Trust, by Horatio Alger, Jr. 1
```

or

```
$ bash parse.sh gutindex.all '23$'
A Tramp Abroad, Part 1, by Mark Twain 23
```

There are a number of ways to approach this. Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I need to take the number as a user input and print the line containing the number.

Comment: Well, you can't just take a number -- otherwise an entry of `'1'` would get the first and third lines. You can append the `'$'` within the script to always match at the end, but you still need a way to match 1 or more digits at the end. The only way to flexibly handle the different search criteria you have set is by passing a regular expression as the argument. You could do a menu that asks more questions, e.g. `"a) match at front; b) match anywhere; c) match at end"`, but you would still be forming the regular expression based on the further answers.